# Stripe Connect -- creating

Tags: stripe-payments

For Stripe Connect, when using the Express Connect setup link, it requests "website" from the user.

[image]

For my use case, I don't need that, and I'd like to autofill or hide it.

I created an account using the node js library, and generated an express link from the account id, but I can't figure out where to set or remove the website field.

Is there a way I can autofill (ideally not allowing the user to edit), or remove the field entirely?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the account, you can [pre-fill](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts#create-account) either the [business_profile.url](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create#create_account-business_profile-url) if they have a website, or you can pre-fill the [business_profile.product_description](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create#create_account-business_profile-product_description) if they do not have a website. By pre-filling either of these account properties, that page in the onboarding flow will be skipped.

Comment: Perfect, that worked! Do you know what the purpose of the buisness_profile.url is? I can't find any documentation on it.

Comment: These fields are used for account underwriting purposes.

Comment: Could you expound a bit on that? I'm new to stripe and payment processing in general.

Comment: Stripe performs necessary fraud checks on accounts — the URL/product description is taken into account when these checks are performed.